# Macro to copy/paste if autofilter results exist

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code. I am applying a filter with different criteria and it works when the filter has rows, but when it doesn't I get the error "Property let procedure not defined and property get procedure did not return an object" at line "My_Range.Parent.AutoFilter.Range.Copy".

How can I skip this empty "paste" to continue with my macro? Thanks!!

```
My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="=FEDERAL"
My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="=No"


    'Copy/paste the visible data to the new worksheet

    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
        With Sheets("Federal").Range("c5")
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        '.Select
    End With


End If
```

Answer (score 0):

easy way to skip trough an error is to write:

```
On Error GoTo myerrorhandler 'put this line on the beginning of you sub/function
     ... your code ...
myerrorhandler: 'after error your code continues to execute from this line
     .... more of your code...
```

or you could just write

```
On Error Resume Next 'your code will resume to next line of code after the error
```

Comment: By the way, beware this also disables all error messages, meaning you should be sure your code doesn't have any other errors or bugs before implementing this. This will also "hide" all the errors if you wish to do debugging or such..